# Что такое cin >> в C++?

Tags: c++

Что такое `cin >>` в C++? Как он работает? Когда его следует использовать?

Answer (score 3):

Пример:

```
cin >> name;       // программа остановится - ожидается имя из клавиатуры
cin >> age;        // программа остановится - ожидается возраст из клавиатуры
```

Когда на клавиатуре задаете, например,

> Юрий<kbd>Enter</kbd>19<kbd>Enter</kbd>

что будет выглядать как:

```
Юрий
19
```

Вы получите в переменной `name` значение `"Юрий"` и в переменной `age` значение `19`.

Comment: что вы привязались к этой "клавиатуре" ??? Это "одно-лишь" средство ввода.

Answer (score 2):

Это ввод через стандартный поток ввода STDIN. Может быть с клавиатуры, может быть через канал, конвеер.